# Tomcat 6 manager app ldap authentication

Tags: tomcat, ldap, tomcat6

Is it possible to map the roles defined for the tomcat 6 manager app to differently named groups in our LDAP?

In the [how to doc for the manager app](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access), it says

> JNDIRealm - Your user and role information is stored in a directory server accessed via LDAP. Add the required role(s) to one or more existing users, and/or create one or more new users with the required role(s) assigned, following the standard procedures for your environment.

I've successfully set up our JNDI Realm point to our LDAP. Now, I'd like to use some existing groups for the roles. For example, rather than create a group named "manager-gui" for the role, I'd rather map the manager-gui role to a group named "serveradmins".

Are there some tweaks I can make to the web.xml for the manager app that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Change the role names in web.xml. So replace all instances of "manager-gui" with "server-admins"

Answer (score 0):

Turn the 'nested groups' option on and make your existing groups members of the 'manager-gui' group.